# Connection to IB broker API PYTHON

Tags: python, api, trading

I test the IB broker API in python. Here are the code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper  

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
     def __init__(self):
         EClient.__init__(self, self) 

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, 0)
app.run()
```

But it seems that the program will not end. It is in an endless loop.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vwZo.png)

And the setting of my TWS is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bZ6r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is by design. The run loop continuously processes any incoming messages from Trader Workstation since they are operating as a client and server across a network asynchronously.

Options for structuring an API program include:

- using an asynchronous framework such as asyncio. This is done in the open source [ib_insync](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync)  library.
- adding an additional thread to handle the run loop.

You would probably interested in the additional programs examples given in the:

[IBKR Traders Academy Course for the TWS Python API](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=45473&cat=none)

It has simple programs to do common tasks with examples of disconnecting.